# I get a Run-time Error #1004 for my VBA code with a Named range?

Tags: vba, excel

why does this code run fine:

```
Sub SelectRange()

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceSheetSum As Worksheet

Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add _
    Name:="ggg", _
    RefersTo:="=Sheet1!A4:L37"
sourceSheet.Select
sourceSheet.Range("A4:L37").Select

End Sub
```

However if I change

```
sourceSheet.Range("A4:L37").Select
```

to:

```
sourceSheet.Range("ggg").Select
```

I receive a run-time error 1004

Comment: Sorry I let you down ;( Will do better next time! Btw. my upvotes don't count as I have a too low ranking.

Comment: The name is global, so you can either add it to the sheet `sourceSheet.Names.Add` instead, or `Application.Range("ggg").Select`

Comment: Your sheet's name is `Tabelle1`, use it in `RefersTo` instead of `Sheet1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, it will create "ggg" named range from cells "A4:L37" in "Tabelle1" sheet.

Afterwards, it sets another Range `MyNamedRange` to the named `Range("ggg")` - this step is not necessary, I just like to work with variables for `Range`.

At the end, it selects `MyNamedRange`.

**Code**

```
Sub SelectRange()

Dim sourceBook          As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet         As Worksheet
Dim sourceSheetSum      As Worksheet
Dim MyNamedRange        As Range

Set sourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

' create the named range "ggg"
sourceBook.Names.Add _
                Name:="ggg", _
                RefersTo:="=" & sourceSheet.Name & "!A4:L37"

Set MyNamedRange = Range("ggg") ' <-- set the Range to your NamedRange "ggg"

sourceSheet.Activate '<-- activate the sheet first
MyNamedRange.Select '<-- select the Named Range

End Sub
```

Comment: Yours posted while I was typing mine, and your comments are better.  But I think that since `ggg` already refers to `sourceSheet`, the `sourceSheet.Activate` statement may be redundant.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld actually I found this "the hard way", if your `ActiveSheet` is let's say "Sheet2", you will get a run-time error when trying to `MyNamedRange.Select` before Activating the `sourceSheet`

Comment: You can avoid the .Activate with `Application.GoTo MyNamedRange, True`

Comment: Interesting.  When I first tested it, with Sheet2 showing, it worked fine; but if I specifically activate Sheet2 (eg. `Sheet2.Activate`).  Then I get the error.  And there is conflicting information in `Help`.

Comment: @Slai I know, I like the 2-steps though (just own preference), now be supportive here ;)

Comment: ok +1 :] but to me it seems like he wants the named range to refer to a different sheet (assuming the code is from Record Macro)

Comment: @Slai it might be, then I'll change `RefersTo:="=" & sourceSheet.Name & "!A4:L37"` to `WhateverSheet.Name` he wants :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. It was really frustrating, especially because there are dozens of tutorials out there, that claimed a simple line of Range("ggg").Select would work.

Comment: By the way me too I am used to activate in two phases instead of using `Application.Goto`, but may be we should both think of switching to the shorter version suggested by @Slai. Unless there is a justification for the longer version, atm i personally dont find any.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

SourceSheet.Range(Names.Item("ggg")).Select

Comment: Side note: "Try this" is very poor explanation of the proposed solution.